# How do i draw lines with HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, line, carousel

I have made this layout for my page.

[image]

with this css

```
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 68%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000 \9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 2px solid #527BBD;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  background-color: #D91C23;
}
```

However, I need to create a slider coin with connecting lines like this:

[image]

can anyone help? thanks in advance!

Comment: please ... provide your code .

Comment: please share your work done so far.

Comment: actually i havent added anything yet to add the lines for my images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SVG was mentioned, here just an example:

```html
<svg>
   <rect x=20 y=20 width=210 height=1 style=stroke:grey />
   <circle cx=20 cy=20 r=10 stroke=black stroke-width=1 fill=white />
   <circle cx=90 cy=20 r=10 stroke=black stroke-width=1 fill=red />
   <circle cx=160 cy=20 r=10 stroke=black stroke-width=1 fill=white />
   <circle cx=230 cy=20 r=10 stroke=black stroke-width=1 fill=white />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and in your html file

```
<div>foo</div>
<hr/>
<div>bar</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could just do it in SVG. It's reactive to DOM events just like HTML.You can even use [SVG in jQuery](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)